# Как с помощью closest() найти получить соседний блок?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

С помощью closest() b addEventListener() я могу получить родителя элемента при нажатии на кнопку. Но как я могу получить блок с классом .text? Есть ли метод у блока, чтобы вернуть дочерний блок с определенным классом? Можно примерный код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.button').onclick = function(e) {
  const text = Array
    .from(e.target.closest('.parent').children)
    .filter(e => e.className === 'text');
  console.log(text[0]); // пустой массив если такого класса не будет в дочерних
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="button">button</div>
  <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *// throws error если такого класса не будет в дочерних* - вы уверены в этом? Какая ошибка будет?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, вернее не ошибка, а просто `undefined`, т.к. массив пустой будет

Answer (score 1):

У html элементов есть `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll` методы для поиска внутри этого элемента.

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const parent = e.target.closest('.parent');
  const text = parent.querySelector('.text');
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="button">button</div>
  <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```